# Re-skinning Site

Tags: themes, css

I have a website that I would like to re-skin for a short while as a form of advertising. I however cannot see where in the editor-style.css I would do this - this the top of my code :

```
/*

Theme Name: Starkers

*/

/*

Used to style the TinyMCE editor.

*/
html .mceContentBody {
    max-width:640px;

}
* {
    font-family: Georgia, "Bitstream Charter", serif;
    color: #444; 
    line-height: 1.5;

}
p,
dl,
td,
th,
ul,
ol,
blockquote {
    font-size: 16px;

}
tr th,

thead th,

label,

tr th,

thead th {

    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, "Nimbus Sans L", sans-serif;

}
pre {

    font-family: "Courier 10 Pitch", Courier, monospace;

}

code, code var {
    font-family: Monaco, Consolas, "Andale Mono", "DejaVu Sans Mono", monospace;

}
body, input, textarea {

    font-size: 12px;

    line-height: 18px;

}
hr {
    background-color: #E7E7E7; 

    border:0;

    height: 1px;

    margin-bottom: 18px;

    clear:both;

}
```

Am I even looking in the right place? I am sure there is a really easy, simple way of doing this as it is a popular option.

Answer (score 2):

*editor-style.css* is used to style TinyMCE, the rich-text-editor employed by WordPress.

Look for a plain *style.css* file in your theme - if it has been written with Starkers as a base, it ought to have one.

I don't mean to be impolite, but if you could not figure out that you were looking at the wrong file, you might want to make sure you have a backup of the stylesheet before editing it.

Comment: HI yes, I did find the style.css after, initially I couldn't see it anywhere. And yep, not that experienced in this so trying to pick my way through, no offence taken and will be keeping a back up! the top of the style.css is belo :